# Can anyone please explain the output of the following code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   printf("%d, %d", ~x-x>>1, ~x-x<<1);

    return 0;
}
```

output is -2, -6

how is this code working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The `~` flips every bit of your number in base-2 so you will get `1...10` for `0...01`. In Two's complement `1...10` means `-2`.

The output of the following code is `-2`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   printf("%d\n", ~x);

   return 0;
}
```

Then, output of the following code is `-3`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   printf("%d\n", ~x-x);

   return 0;
}
```

`>>` and `<<` operators do the bitwise shift in right and left. So for `11..10` you will get `11..100` when do the left shit and this would multiple your number in 2. Also, for `11..10` you will get `11..1` when do the right shift which divide your number by 2.

At the end:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   printf("%d\n", ~x);

   printf("%d\n", x>>1);
   printf("%d\n", x<<1);

   printf("%d\n", ~x-x);

   printf("%d, %d\n", ~x-x>>1, ~x-x<<1);

    return 0;
}
```

gives you:

```
-2
0
2
-3
-2, -6
```

Comment: Left shifting a negative value leads to undefined behavior per the C standard.

Comment: Yes, here I use the arithmetic shift definition.